# Is it possible to set mapSideCombine and keyOrdering on one ShuffleDependency

Tags: apache-spark

There are two options/attributes `mapSideCombine`  and `keyOrdering`  that can be set on the ShuffleDependency .

I noticed that reduceByKey and sortByKey only set one of these two attributes for each method,

I would ask if it is possible to set `mapSideCombine` to true and set an Ordering object for `keyOrdering` for the same ShuffleDependency. If so,could some one please give me an example?

I ask so because in the SortShuffleWriter#write method, there are following code:

```
sorter = if (dep.mapSideCombine) {
  require(dep.aggregator.isDefined, "Map-side combine without Aggregator specified!")
  new ExternalSorter[K, V, C](
    context, dep.aggregator, Some(dep.partitioner), dep.keyOrdering, dep.serializer)
}
```

Here, if `dep.mapSideCombine` is true, and if `dep.keyOrdering` can only be None，we can provide None instead of `dep.keyOrdering` to the `ExternalSorter` constructor?

Comment: Could someone help on the question? Thanks